# HTML in JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm tryng to put html into javascript code:

```
       document.write("<a class=\"twitter-timeline\"href=\"https://twitter.com/test\"          data-widget-    id=\"248798161076883457\">Tweets by @test</a>
             <script>!function(d,s,id){
              var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if(!d.getElementById(id))
              {js=d.createElement(s);
          js.id=id;js.src=\"//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
       }(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");
       </script>
        ");
```

}

The error message is: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
what's wrong?
Thx!

Comment: change `//platform.twitter.com` to either `http://platform.twitter.com` or `platform.twitter.com`

Comment: @karthikr: No need to do that, that's a valid protocol-relative URL.

Comment: document.write is a bad function to use for several reasons including security issues.  Consider instead using an element's innerHTML property to set HTML into your document, which works better and does not have the same security issues.

Comment: document.write("<a class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/test'  data-widget- id='248798161076883457'>Tweets by @test</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');</script>"); ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Glad it works! Which script you used in the end? the 1 that I shared or the 1 shared by user1666993 . Thanks

Comment: And please tick the right answer. Updating the title of the question as solved is not the right way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A string in javascript must not go over multiple lines without the right format:

```
   document.write("<a class=\"twitter-timeline\"href=\"https://twitter.com  /test\"          data-widget-    id=\"248798161076883457\">Tweets by @test</a>\
         <script>!function(d,s,id){\
          var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];\
         if(!d.getElementById(id))\
          {js=d.createElement(s);\
      js.id=id;js.src=\"//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";\
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);\
    }\
   }(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");\
   </script>\
    ");
```

In general:

```
string = "Multiple\
Lines\
supported."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<a class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/test'  data-widget- id='248798161076883457'>Tweets by @test</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');</script>"); ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You can use single quotes instead of double quotes inside script! It makes it easier to read and it works perfectly